# How to unbind click and click submit button in and using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to submit form in JQuery but

```
 <input type="submit" id="yesBank" />

 $('#yesBank , #worldBank').on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.blockUI({
            message: 'Getting List'
        });

        //Want to unbind this click JS
        //Want to click on submit button from here $(#yesBank).click("");
        //Unbinding is done so that it does not execute this 
        //I am bound to click this button as server is handling a condition on click of it. but i have to display block ui too
    });
```

My purpose is to block UI. actually when i block UI like this then control does not go to server and page does not reload. Even if i remove preventDefault. Can someone show me the snippet?

Comment: Why don't you just call `$("#form").submit()`?

Comment: Please go through this Spring MVC method ->   @Loggable
  @RequestMapping(value = "save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String lagrePermanent(@ModelAttribute("user") Useruser,
      @ModelAttribute("bankForm") BankFormbankForm, BindingResult res, RedirectAttributes attr,
      @RequestParam(required = false) String pause, @RequestParam(required = false) String yesBank,
      @RequestParam(required = false) String worldBank, @RequestParam(required = false) String finalSubmit, WebRequest wr) {

Comment: If i will not click yesBank then there will be no value sent to String yesBank.

Comment: And if i will not write that JQuery function; then i will not able to block screen

Comment: So i need to execute that Jquery function once and click on yesBank so that same method does not get executed again.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use chaining 
$('#yesBank , #worldBank').on("click", function (e) {

// rest code goes here

     }.off("click")
```

Comment: That will remove the click handler immediately after adding it. You want to call `.off()` inside the handler function.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this -

```
$('#yesBank , #worldBank').on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.blockUI({
            message: 'Getting List'
        });

        $(this).off('click');
    });
```